# Updating mysql database table, set date column of anything earlier than today with today's date

Tags: mysql, sql

I currently have  a database table that I need to do a 'date refresh' on and I'm trying to think of the easiest way to do this since it's almost 8000 records.

There are 18 records that have a date later than today. THe rest are either today or earlier. The column in question is 'next_call_date' and it's a DATE data type.

I'm thinking along these lines:

```
Update dealers
set next_call_date = curdate()
where next_call_date before curdate();
```

Would this be the best way to go about it, assuming the syntax is appropriate?

Comment: You have a syntax error.  Replace `before` with `<`.   Otherwise it's fine.

Comment: That got it, thanks for the confirmation!

Comment: Not sure why this was downvoted.....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For MySql:

Update dealers
set next_call_date = now()
where date(next_call_date)

for Mssql:

Update dealers
set next_call_date = getdate()
where cast(next_call_date as date)